# How to get SQL result more efficiently

Tags: sql, select, count, db2, where-clause

I have a problem with my SQL query in DB2 database. I have to get records from one table based on the count of records from the second table which is connected through some fields. My Query is working very very very slow. I have been trying to find a more efficient way to do it, even use inner join but it was still the same.

```
SELECT * FROM table1

WHERE

    table1.field1 = '9' AND
    table1.field2 <= CURRENT DATE - 1 YEAR AND
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2
    WHERE 
        table2.field1 = '0' AND
        table1.field3 = table2.field2 AND
        table1.field4 = table2.field3 AND
                table1.field5 = table2.field4 AND
        table1.field6 = table2.field5 AND
        table1.field7 = table2.field6 
    ) = 0
WITH UR
```

Comment: we cannot help you unless you share whole the table structure with proper indexes

Comment: Is it enough if I tell you that the fields in table1 are the primary keys of table1, and the keys in table2 are not keys?

Comment: You need to look at the 'explain plan' to find out how the database engine is deciding to process the data. Then you need to decide how you think it should be doing it. And provide access routes it can use to make it more efficient. It is all part of learning about 'databases'.

Comment: You don't need `SELECT COUNT(*)` if you check non-existence. Use `NOT EXISTS` directly

Comment: Side note: date/time should usually be queried upper-bound exclusive - `<` - or you get weird results when dealing with the full precision and paging the rows (in the display sense, not the memory sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be better.  First, change the query to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.field1 = '9' AND  -- do not use single quotes if field1 is a number!
      table1.field2 <= CURRENT DATE - 1 YEAR AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2
                  WHERE table2.field1 = '0' AND
                        table1.field3 = table2.field2 AND
                        table1.field4 = table2.field3 AND
                        table1.field5 = table2.field4 AND 
                        table1.field6 = table2.field5 AND
                        table1.field7 = table2.field6 
                  ) ;
```

Second, make sure that comparisons use the right types `'9'` or `9`?  `'0'` or `0`?

Third, add indexes:

- `table1(field1, field2)`
- `table2(field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field1)`

The ordering for the first five fields for the `table2` index is arbitrary; however, `field1` should come after them.

Comment: Shouldn't field1 be first column in index on table2?

Comment: @Satya - The implication from having a constant for `field1` is that it's a status/flag field, with low cardinality, and the condition won't eliminate very many rows _from the join product_ overall.  The multiple columns from the other table, however, will cut down on far more rows to consider when the optimizer is trying to figure out what the row multiplication will produce, so they come first.  (At least, I think that's what Gordon is getting at - I'm a bit rusty on some of this)

Comment: @Satya . . . Absolutely not.  The columns need to be ordered by the conditions on the outer table first, and then the inner table -- first the match to the outer rows *and then* filtering.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I am asking about the order of columns in suggested index.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ,  index advisor (DB2 LUW) suggests differently. Create copies of syscat.tables and syscat.columns in test library and check index advise for sql "
select *
from testlib.columns c
where c.typename = 'XML'
and not exists
( select 1 
  from testlib.tables t
  where t.type = 'V'
  and t.tabname = c.tabname
  and t.tabschema = c.tabschema )
"

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt I would try:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE
  table1.field1 = '9' AND
  table1.field2 <= CURRENT DATE - 1 YEAR AND
NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM table2
   WHERE 
    table2.field1 = '0' AND
    table1.field3 = table2.field2 AND
    table1.field4 = table2.field3 AND
            table1.field5 = table2.field4 AND
    table1.field6 = table2.field5 AND
    table1.field7 = table2.field6 
)
WITH UR
```

Although it's not possible to make predictions without schemas, data and execution plans

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I've already tried this but it's pretty much the same. I thought I was doing something wrong but it seems like I'm gonna have to wait, thank you :)